# Update datagridview from usercontrol using event button click form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm try to update datagridview in usercontrol using event buttonclick from another form. But i still can't resolve it.

I have form1, already display usercontrol in panel.

Code from usercontrol like this.

```
public partial class suppliers : UserControl
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HENDRICK;Initial Catalog=mydb");

    public void displaydata()
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id_supplier] as 'ID' ,[nama_supplier] as 'Nama' ,[telepon_supplier] as 'Telepon' ,[alamat_supplier] as 'Alamat' FROM[mydb].[dbo].[supplier]",conn);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        datagridsuppliers.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }

    public suppliers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displaydata();
    }

    private void btnaddsuppliers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        new PopupEffect.transparentBg(frm, new addsuppliers());
    }
}
```

When I click the btnaddsuppliers, the addsuppliers form will appear, that is useful for inserting data.

The code from addsuppliers form like this.

```
public partial class addsuppliers : Form
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HENDRICK;Initial Catalog=mydb");
        suppliers supp = new suppliers();

        void reset_txtbox()
        {
            txtnama.Text = "";
            txttelepon.Text = "";
            txtalamat.Text = "";
        }

        public addsuppliers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                String insertQuery = "insert into [mydb].[dbo].[supplier] ([id_supplier],[nama_supplier],[telepon_supplier],[alamat_supplier]) values (@id,@nama,@telepon,@alamat)";

                cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "SP1");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", txtnama.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telepon", txttelepon.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", txtalamat.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
                Bunifu.Snackbar.Show(this.FindForm(), "Add Supplier Successfully.", 2000, Snackbar.Views.SnackbarDesigner.MessageTypes.Success);

                supp.displaydata();
                reset_txtbox();
            }
            catch
            {
                Bunifu.Snackbar.Show(this.FindForm(), "Failed,Check database connection.", 2000, Snackbar.Views.SnackbarDesigner.MessageTypes.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when btnadd is clicked, the database has been updated but the datagridview on usercontrol is not updated automatically.

I have tried to use the call displaydata() function to update the DataGridView. But the result of DataGridView remains unchanged or not updated.

Please help to resolve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: You want to call the user control's displaydata from addsuppliers' btnadd_Click event handler?

Comment: The usercontrol is already displayed. I like to update usercontrol.

Comment: The supp reference in your addsuppliers form is a new instance. It's not the same with the user control which is displayed.